# Missing commands in drush 9.3

Tags: drush, composer

I have installed drush 9 as dependency of my drupal 8 project as explained in: http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/

```
cd ${D8_PROJECT}
composer require drush/drush
```

Then, I have installed `drush launcher` as explained in: https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher (ubuntu)

```
wget -O drush.phar https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher/releases/download/0.6.0/drush.phar
chmod +x drush.phar
sudo mv drush.phar /usr/local/bin/drush
```

Everything is working fine except that some command are missing. Here is the list of command I have:

```
Drush Commandline Tool 9.3.0

Run `drush help [command]` to view command-specific help.  Run `drush topic` to read even more documentation.

 Available commands:                                                                                                
 _global:                                                                                                           
   help                                 Display usage details for a command.                                        
   list                                 List available commands.                                                    
   browse                               Display a link to a given path or open link in a browser.                   
   runserver (rs, serve)                Runs PHP's built-in http server for development.                            
   updatedb (updb)                      Apply any database updates required (as with running update.php).           
   version                              Show Drush version.                                                         
   generate (gen)                       Generate boilerplate code for modules/plugins/services etc.                 
   drupal:directory (dd)                Return the filesystem path for modules/themes and other key folders.        
   user:login (uli)                     Display a one time login link for user ID 1, or another user.               
   entity:updates (entup)               Apply pending entity schema updates.                                        
   updatedb:status (updbst)             List any pending database updates.                                          
   config:pull (cpull)                  Export and transfer config from one environment to another.                 
   pm:security (sec)                    Check Drupal Composer packages for pending security updates.                
 cache:                                                                                                             
   cache:get (cg)                       Fetch a cached object and display it.                                       
   cache:clear (cc)                     Clear a specific cache, or all Drupal caches.                               
   cache:set (cs)                       Cache an object expressed in JSON or var_export() format.                   
   cache:rebuild (cr, rebuild)          Rebuild a Drupal 8 site.                                                    
 core:                                                                                                              
   core:status (status, st)             An overview of the environment - Drush and Drupal.                          
   core:init (init)                     Enrich the bash startup file with bash aliases and a smart command prompt.  
   core:rsync (rsync)                   Rsync Drupal code or files to/from another server using ssh.                
   core:execute (exec, execute)         Execute a shell command. Usually used with a site alias.                    
   core:edit (conf, config)             Edit drushrc, site alias, and Drupal settings.php files.                    
   core:topic (topic)                   Read detailed documentation on a given topic.                               
 php:                                                                                                               
   php:eval (eval, ev)                  Evaluate arbitrary php code after bootstrapping Drupal (if available).      
   php:script (scr)                     Run php a script after a full Drupal bootstrap.                             
 site:                                                                                                              
   site:ssh (ssh)                       Connect to a Drupal site's server via SSH.                                  
   site:set (use)                       Set a site alias that will persist for the current session.                 
   site:alias (sa)                      Show site alias details, or a list of available site aliases.               
   site:alias-convert (sa-convert, sac) Convert legacy site alias files to the new yml format.                      
   site:install (si, sin)               Install Drupal along with modules/themes/configuration/profile.             
 sql:                                                                                                               
   sql:connect                          A string for connecting to the DB.                                          
   sql:create                           Create a database.                                                          
   sql:drop                             Drop all tables in a given database.                                        
   sql:cli (sqlc)                       Open a SQL command-line interface using Drupal's credentials.               
   sql:query (sqlq)                     Execute a query against a database.                                         
   sql:dump                             Exports the Drupal DB as SQL using mysqldump or equivalent.                 
   sql:sync                             Copy DB data from a source site to a target site. Transfers data via rsync.
```

Where are the `user-create`, `role-create` and other commands?

... and what is really weird, is the fact that yesterday I did use the `drush locale-update` command... and today this command is also gone.

Comment: According to the Docs, it is user:create for Drush 9: https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/user/user:create/ Same for locale:update: https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/locale/locale:update/ Do those commands work?

Comment: This should better be asked on [GitHub](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher/issues).

Comment: Under aliases it says `drush user-create`, how do you explain that?

Comment: I missed that to be honest, but OP didn't say that `drush user-create` doesn't work, only that it doesn't show up in the list of commands.  And looking at the list of commands, `user:create` might show up but not `user-create`.

Answer (score 2):

I finally understood my problem.

Looking at the @M.Schmitt comment, I could find that both syntax are working: `user:create` and `user-create`. A lot of commands are not available when there is no connection to the database. When I ran `drush` on a multisite installation without default site, I get the small list of commands; when I ran `drush @alias`, I get all the commands.